# Showing full height layout above recyclerview inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As the title says. I'm trying to display extremely complex layout with a full height of the viewport but I need it scrollable because under it there is a simple recyclerview with some items. I already thought about putting everything inside a multi type recyclerview adapter but the logic of the upper layout is so complex that I don't think it's possible.

I tried using `NestedScrollView` with `fillViewport` set to true but I'm stuck defining dimensions of this upper layout and recyclerview below it. Everything needs to be inside one layout because scrollview can't have more than one child, but when I put everything in a linearlayout and set the upper layout to match_parent it's showing fullscreen until data loads in the recyclerview below it. Then it's treating this upper layout as if it was wrap_content.

I'm out of ideas how can I do something like this. Preferably best would be to have some sort of `ViewGroup` which would support scrolling and resize the recyclerview below it as we scroll, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: please provide xml file code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the layout to something like this:

```
<NestedScrollView - height:match_parent>
  <LinearLayout - height:wrap_content>
    <LinearLayout(topview) - height:wrap_content/>
    <RecyclerView - height:wrap_content />
  </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

And then you programmatically change the height of the "topview" to equal nestedscrollview.